# Best way to create a MySQL/SQL select statement that totals (count 'AS' columns)?

Tags: mysql, select, count, case

I am having some trouble finding how to total 'AS' columns in my select statement.

example issue:

```
Select *,

count(case when column1 = 'yes' then (value +1) end) AS Column1Count,
count(case when column2 = 'yes' then (value +1) end) AS Column2Count,
(Column1Count + Column2Count) AS Column1and2TOTAL

From mytable
```

The above does not appear to work, unless I create a count(case) that includes previous 'As' columns initial criteria.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Some of my statements become quite (and seemingly unnecessarily) complex.

Comment: Unfortunately mySQL doesn't have the TSQL equivalent of `cross apply` which would make this easy. Short of making the `count`s as a subquery, joining on to it and summing it up (which would hit the table twice, as well as replicating any `where` logic, so, inefficient perhaps) I think the fastest way is to replicate the `case` in your `sum`. Leaving this as a comment as I hope I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your query as below:

```
 Select Column1Count,
        Column2Count,
        (Column1Count + Column2Count) AS Column1and2TOTAL
 From (
       select count(case when column1 = 'yes' then (value +1) end) AS Column1Count, 
              count(case when column2 = 'yes' then (value +1) end) AS Column2Count 
       from  mytable) as subquery
```

This will work.